# You can not implicitly convert "RESTfullApi.Models.Product []" to "RESTfullApi.Models.Product"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

i'm trying to learn how to create Web Api, and i have an error.

I don't know what to do, first it required to use sufix M when i used it, VS show me error:

> You cannnot implicitly convert "RESTfullApi.Models.Product []" to
>   "RESTfullApi.Models.Product"

I was trying to find answer on the internet but nothing explain this case.
Maybe you know what is wrong with it?

This is tutorial in which i practice:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

ProductsController.cs

```
using RESTfullApi.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace RESTfullApi.Controllers
{
    public class ProductsController : ApiController
    {
        Product products = new Product[]
        {
            new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Pizza Margarita", Category = "Pizza", Price = 13.00M },
            new Product { Id = 2, Name = "Pizza Double Cheese", Category = "Pizza", Price = 17.00M }
        };

        public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
        {
            return products;
        }
    }
}
```

Product.cs (Model)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace RESTfullApi.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Product products = new Product[]` you are saying that you have a variable named `products` of type `Product` - a single instance of product, and you are assigning it an array of products - type mismatch. Change variable type to `Product[]`. Or you can simply use `var` for declaration, which would spare you some thinking in the future (`var products = new Product[] {`)

Answer (score 3):

Message is self explanatory. Change `products` to

```
Product[] products = new Product[]
{
    new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Pizza Margarita", Category = "Pizza", Price = 13.00M },
    new Product { Id = 2, Name = "Pizza Double Cheese", Category = "Pizza", Price = 17.00M }
};
```